# most convenient pattern for printing a timestamp using java.util.Formatter

Tags: java

java.util.Formatter is a very handy standard tool for string substitution/replacement.

As far as I can find, the easiest way to print a timestamp (ie 2015-01-01 12:10:05.492) is to use the following:

```
String.format("timestamp %1$tF %1$tT.%1$tL", new Date());
```

`%#$tF %#$tT.%#$tL` is a little more code than I'd like.

Without using extra objects such as SimpleDateFormat is there are more convenient way to acheive the same outcome?

Comment: Using a `SimpleDateFormat` would at least make the code/pattern more readable -- is there a specific reason for not using it?

Comment: i'm hoping to avoid having to create extra objects all of the place just to be able to log some values when debugging

Comment: `String.format("timestamp %tF %<tT.%<tL", new Date())` is a start.  If you haven't read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), I recommend it.

Comment: i like it @VGR - i did read the docs but obviously not enough ;)